# How to list queues including queue name from AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-sqs

I am looking for a way to get a list of my queue names from AWS. I am currently using the code below but the listing returned from AWS only includes the queue URLs (and other attributes) and not the queue names:

```
using (var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
{
    ListQueuesResponse response = sqsClient.ListQueues(new Amazon.SQS.Model.ListQueuesRequest());
    List<QueueResponse> qrs = new List<QueueResponse>();
    foreach (var queueURL in response.QueueUrls)
    {
        GetQueueAttributesResponse attributesResponse = sqsClient.GetQueueAttributes(new GetQueueAttributesRequest(queueURL, new List<string> { "All" }));
        qrs.Add(new QueueResponse { QueueURL = queueURL, MessagesAvailable = attributesResponse.ApproximateNumberOfMessages, MessagesInFlight = attributesResponse.ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible  });
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any advice in solving the above problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`'Try QueueARN which is something like this arn:aws:sqs:region:account-id:queuename '`

```
 namespace Amazon.SQS.Model
{
   public class GetQueueAttributesResult : AmazonWebServiceResponse
   {
    public GetQueueAttributesResult();

    public int ApproximateNumberOfMessages { get; }
    public int ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed { get; }
    public int ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible { get; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTimestamp { get; }
    public int DelaySeconds { get; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedTimestamp { get; }
    public int MaximumMessageSize { get; }
    public int MessageRetentionPeriod { get; }
    public string Policy { get; }
    public string QueueARN { get; }
    public int VisibilityTimeout { get; }
   }
}
```